# Setting an image im menuItem and changing the backcolor of a menuItem when MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, menuitem

I have a menu as shown in the figure below :

[image]

The XAML is :

```
<MenuItem .....>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="Images/Add.png">
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

I am not getting any image at runtime. Am I making any mistake in the above XAML?

Also, If anyone knows how to change the backColor of a menuItem on MouseOver, Please suggest.

Comment: How did you make your menu to look like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
<MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
    </MenuItem>
```

Comment: I removed my previous style and added the style as you suggested above. But I never get the background of MenuItem = blue or green

Comment: Is the background of your image transparent?

Comment: Yes background of my image is transparent.